How do I get the entire contents of a request's original request header using python
such as
POST /service/rapture/session HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.136.155:8081
Content-Length: 39
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Nexus-UI: true
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.5672.127 Safari/537.36
NX-ANTI-CSRF-TOKEN: 0.74934606792014381.1.691978768.1713947526; _gid=GA1.1.1983366476.1713947526; metabase.TIMEOUT=aliv
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*

how can i get this header?
i have used requests method, but the request header content it returns is very small.

If you have a response object, then response.request should be an object that represents the request which produced that response.  And it has a .headers attribute which should be all of the headers from the request.

The requests library encapsulates Python's network request API in multiple layers and only provides high-level interfaces. Therefore, it's not quite possible to achieve this with requests.
Obtaining Response Headers
This is an example of getting raw response headers from low-level API:
import http.client
host = "docs.python.org"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request("GET", "/3/", headers={"Host": host})
response = conn.getresponse()
print(list(response.headers.raw_items()))

The above code generates an output like this:
[('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
 ('Content-Length', '19561'),
 ('server', 'nginx'),
 ('content-type', 'text/html'),
 ('last-modified', 'Wed, 24 Apr 2024 21:00:51 GMT'),
 ('etag', '"66297303-4c69"'),
 ('x-clacks-overhead', 'GNU Terry Pratchett'),
 ('strict-transport-security', 'max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload'),
 ('Via', '1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish'),
 ('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes'),
 ('Date', 'Thu, 25 Apr 2024 02:48:30 GMT'),
 ('Age', '20831'),
 ('X-Served-By', 'cache-lga21956-LGA, cache-tyo11964-TYO'),
 ('X-Cache', 'HIT, HIT'),
 ('X-Cache-Hits', '19, 1'),
 ('X-Timer', 'S1714013311.518366,VS0,VE1'),
 ('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding')]

Obtaining Request Headers
The process of obtaining the request header is more tricky because many fields in the header are added before the request is sent. In order to achieve this, the request needs to be sent manually. This is an example code:
def prepare_request(conn, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked):
    # Modified from http.client.HTTPConnection._send_output
    header_names = frozenset(k.lower() for k in headers)
    skips = {}
    if 'host' in header_names:
        skips['skip_host'] = 1
    if 'accept-encoding' in header_names:
        skips['skip_accept_encoding'] = 1
    conn.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
    if 'content-length' not in header_names:
        if 'transfer-encoding' not in header_names:
            encode_chunked = False
            content_length = conn._get_content_length(body, method)
            if content_length is None:
                if body is not None:
                    encode_chunked = True
                    conn.putheader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
            else:
                conn.putheader('Content-Length', str(content_length))
    else:
        encode_chunked = False
    for hdr, value in headers.items():
        conn.putheader(hdr, value)
    if isinstance(body, str):
        body = body.encode('latin-1')

    return body, encode_chunked

import http.client
host = "docs.python.org"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
headers = {"Host": host} # Your custom headers here
body, encode_chunked = prepare_request(conn, 'GET', '/3/', None, headers, False)
raw_headers = conn._buffer[:]
conn.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
print(raw_headers)

This generates an output like:
[b'GET /3/ HTTP/1.1',
 b'Accept-Encoding: identity',
 b'Host: docs.python.org']

Although this approach achieves your goal, it loses the advantages of the high-level libraries. Constructing the result mannually is more recommended.
